# Is it possible to use E4 for Eclipse plug-ins

Tags: eclipse-plugin, e4

It's probably an easy question, so here is why I'm confused:

As far as I can tell, you [can't mix E3 (compatibility) with E4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43846245/mix-e3-and-e4-in-one-application). Your application is either E3 or E4.

I created multiple Eclipse plug-ins, all using E3, that all still work in the current Eclipse, so my guess is that Eclipse is build on the compatibility layer. I can't check all the plug-ins, but as an example `ErrorViewPart` is extending `ViewPart`, so that's E3 right there.

On the other hand [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12764483/how-can-i-create-a-view-using-the-e4-programming-model-to-be-a-plug-in-for-eclip) seems to indicate mixing E3 with E4 is possible, albeit not easy. And promises that it might be easy starting with Eclipse 4.3. We are now at 4.9.

I want to create a new plug-in. Can I use E4? What is the recommended framework?

Comment: We are now at 4.9. In Eclipse 4.x plug-ins based on 3.x are supported via the compatibility layer. This means, you can mix 4.x and 3.x, but as long as you have 3.x stuff your RCP application must contain the compatibility layer: https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2013/february/article3.php

Comment: There isn't one recommended framework. The core of Eclipse is always e4 with the 3.x compatibility layer sat on top of that if needed. If you don't need any compatibility mode stuff you can just write a 'pure e4' RCP otherwise either just e3 APIs or some mix of e3 and e4.